How to call Open AI Transcription Audio from React Native. Expo GO. Invalid file format. Supported formats
I have a react native app with expo go. The functionality is simple, I tap record, and then stop, and the audio file should be sent to Open AI and transcribe it to text.
However I am having difficulties as it requires a File, not an URI.
I get this error:
> ents/ExponentExperienceData/@levm38/ai-reminders/recording_1718887602296.mp3"}
> ERROR  Failed to transcribe audio: [AxiosError: Request failed with
> status code 400]  LOG  Response data: {"error": {"code": null,
> "message": "Invalid file format. Supported formats: ['flac', 'm4a',
> 'mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'mpga', 'oga', 'ogg', 'wav', 'webm']", "param":
> null, "type": "invalid_request_error"}}

The code is as follows:
  const stopRecording = async () => {
    console.log('Stopping recording...');
    setRecording(null);
    setIsRecording(false);
    await recording?.stopAndUnloadAsync();

    const uri = recording?.getURI();
    if (uri) {
      const timestamp = Date.now();

      try {
        console.log('Recording saved as M4A:', uri);

        // Fetch duration of the recording
        const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync({ uri });
        const { durationMillis } = await sound.getStatusAsync();
        await sound.unloadAsync();

        await saveRecording(uri, timestamp, durationMillis);

        // Read the M4A file content into a Base64 string
        const m4aBase64String = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, {
          encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
        });

        console.log('M4A Base64 string length:', m4aBase64String.length);

        // Convert Base64 string back to Blob
        const m4aBlob = await base64ToBlob(m4aBase64String, 'audio/mp4');

        // Check the contents of the Blob
        const m4aBase64Check = await readBlobAsBase64(m4aBlob);
        console.log('M4A Base64 check:', m4aBase64Check === m4aBase64String);

        // Call the transcription function with the Blob object
        await transcribeAudio(m4aBlob);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to save recording as M4A:', error);
      }
    }
  };

  const transcribeAudio = async (file) => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', {
        uri: file.uri,
        name: 'speech.m4a',
        type: 'audio/mp4',
      });
      formData.append('model', 'whisper-1');
      formData.append('response_format', 'verbose_json');
      formData.append('timestamp_granularities', 'segment');

      const headers = {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${openaiApiKey}`,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      };

      console.log('FormData contents:');
      // formData.forEach((value, key) => {
      //   if (key === 'file') {
      //     console.log(`FormData key: ${key}, value: File of type ${value.type}, size: ${value.size}`);
      //   } else {
      //     console.log(`FormData key: ${key}, value: ${value}`);
      //   }
      // });

      console.log('Transcribing audio...');
      const response = await axios.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions', formData, { headers });
      console.log('Transcription response:', response.data); // Log full response for debugging

      // Extract the actual transcription text from the response
      const transcriptionText = response.data.text;
      console.log('Transcription text:', transcriptionText);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to transcribe audio:', error);
      if (error.response) {
        console.log('Response data:', error.response.data);
      }
    }
  };

If I check my logs  I get this:
> LOG  Recording saved as MP3:
> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2C4F636D-9A6C-4FAD-976D-3A4D7D7B2EE7/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/@levm38/ai-reminders/recording_1718887873585.mp3
> LOG  Recording saved {"duration": 1858, "timestamp": 1718887873585,
> "uri":
> "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2C4F636D-9A6C-4FAD-976D-3A4D7D7B2EE7/Documents/ExponentExperienceData/@levm38/ai-reminders/recording_1718887873585.mp3"}
> LOG  Converting Base64 to Blob...  LOG  Blob conversion successful:
> {"_data": {"__collector": {}, "blobId":
> "92385B71-9F4F-4F40-9D2B-D09A84B06AF6", "name": "Unknown", "offset":
> 0, "size": 68915, "type": "audio/mpeg"}}  ERROR  Failed to transcribe
> audio: [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400]  LOG 
> Response data: {"error": {"code": null, "message": "Invalid file
> format. Supported formats: ['flac', 'm4a', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'mpeg',
> 'mpga', 'oga', 'ogg', 'wav', 'webm']", "param": null, "type":
> "invalid_request_error"}}


I suspect there is something wrong with the base64 to blob conversion. Can you try dumping the contents of the blob and check if its the same data as in the saved mp3?

I made some modificatoins, instead of saving as mp3, I left the default which is m4a, I convert to base 64 and back to see if the length and value matches and it does. I am still getting the same format error.
